# react Using removed babel5 options. Check out corresponding stage x presets

Tags: javascript, npm, babeljs

I am hitting with this error. I am building a `react-native` app that will and I am not using webpack. I have `.babelrc` file along with my `package.json` which looks like:

```
{
  "presets": ["react-native", "es2015"],
}
```

How can I remove this error.??

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?